# R presentation not showing plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have this R presentation that I want to run, however the presentation is not knitting and gives this error:

[image]

Any help would be much appreciated, also is it possible to insert my codes for reading data, data cleaning and plotting etc. and if yes where should this go?

Thank you

````
---
title: "Presentation"
author: "Harold"
date: "5/24/2021"
output: ioslides_presentation
---

```{r setup}
library(ggplot2)```


Introduction

* Covid-19 has halted the travel of Australia in an unprecendented way. Arrivals and departure have pummet by over 95% across many different groups. 

* During this time, as many as 400,000 people have been unable to otherwise fly into Australia if not for the closed borders. 

## Slide with Bullets

- Bullet 1
- Bullet 2
- Bullet 3

## Slide with R Output

```{r cars, echo = TRUE}
summary(cars)```

## Slide with Plot

```{r}
ggplot(Visa_arrival, aes(x=Visa_arrival$Visa, y=Visa_arrival$`number of arrival`, fill=as.factor(Visa_arrival$Month))) + geom_bar(stat='identity', position='dodge')  ```
````

Comment: You've not defined the `Visa_arrival` data frame.  Also, there's no need to specify the data frame within the `aes()` call.  In fact, it's usually wrong to do so.  Once `Visa_arrival` is defined, `aes(x=Visa, ...)` will suffice.

Comment: Should I define the dataframe within the same slide? Or do it somewhere else, I tried inserting my codes in the top section at {r setup} but it still shoots out the same error message.